# Framework not found: iphonesimulator, iphoneos, -fprofile-instr-generate

Tags: ios, xcode, build, frameworks

Using Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014) and Swift 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31).

I am unable to fully compile our iOS app. Our set up is an iOS app workspace referencing another iOS project which is a dynamic framework. It also uses Cocoapods and has a "Pods" project. No matter how I compile (build, test, etc), and even though all source files exhibit no errors, Xcode fails to compile and complains about frameworks not found.

Specifically, when "Build for... Running" is run with the destination device as iPhone or Generic iOS Device, I get this message:

`ld: framework not found - L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos`

if I build for running using the simulator as destination, I get the following message:

`ld: framework not found -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator`

...if I build for testing for a simulator:
`ld: framework not found -fprofile-instr-generate`

...finally, if I build for testing for Generic iOS Device:
`ld: framework not found -fprofile-instr-generate`

**Screenshots**
[image: Xcode error build for running screenshot 1]
Xcode error build for running 
[image: Xcode error build for testing screenshot]
Xcode error build for testing

I have tried verifying my build settings (that they include relevant libs and include `$(inherited)`), including Library and Framework search paths. I've tried restarting Xcode. I've tried restarting OS X. I've cleaned the project, cleaned build folder, and deleted DerivedData. None of these have solved the issue.

**Framework Search Paths**
[image: framework search paths build settings screenshot]

**Library Search Paths**
[image: library search paths build settings screenshot]

This started happening after I migrated some storyboard and UI files from the application project to the framework project. I also modified our navigation from a sliding drawer to a `UITabBar`. I fear something may have gone wrong in the `git merge` process that was executed regarding the tab bar. Reverting to an older branch fixes the issue but obviously does not contain the desired new features. I'm risking losing or having to re-do several hours of work if I revert. Please advise. Thank you.